# How to integrate a node js app with flask app

Tags: node.js, flask, server

I am currently using a flask app. I am trying to integrate a node js app with it. Node js app has some functionalities that I want to use.

The link to node js app is:

https://github.com/rulematrix/rule-matrix-js

There they have a section named usage

> import { RuleMatrixApp, RuleList, Streams, ConditionalStreams } from
> 'rule-matrix-js';
>
> const input = null; const styles: RuleMatrixStyles = {   flowWidth:
> 30,   // mode: 'matrix',   rectWidth: 45,   rectHeight: 27,   color:
> labelColor,   displayEvidence: true,   // displayFidelity: false,   //
> displayFlow: false,   zoomable: true, }; const model: RuleList = new
> RuleList(require('./test_data/model.json')); const streams: Streams =
> createStreams(require('./test_data/stream.json')); // const streams:
> ConditionalStreams =
> createConditionalStreams(require('./test_data/stream_cond.json')); //
> const support: Support | SupportMat =
> require('./test_data/support.json'); const support: Support |
> SupportMat = require('./test_data/support_mat.json');
> model.support(support);
>
> ReactDOM.render(   
>    ,
> document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement );

Can I integrate the node js app with the flask app?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrating"?

Comment: I want to use the node js app inside the flask app.